# Make angularjs select option searchable on browser

Tags: angularjs, select

Can I make the option text searchable from browser's search functionality ( Ctrl + F)?
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/o4RJ2N

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the browsers search funcitonality. Do you mean the address bar?

Comment: so, with Ctrl + F browser search?

Comment: Yes, Ctrl + F functionality

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is searchable, but you can search for something in your array manually with an input field. Just extend your code (below `<select>`) with this:

```
<input ng-model="search"/>
<div ng-repeat="i in items | filter:search" ng-show="search">
  {{i}}
</div>
```

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fb62vlK5JlcNQyDQ8y4E?p=preview)